# i have issues while doing bundle using vue js with electron

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, electron

Installing vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder...

- vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder@1.4.4
  updated 1 package in 34.427s
  Successfully installed plugin: vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder

Invoking generator for vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder...
 WARN  Devtools extensions are broken in Electron 6.0.0 and greater
 WARN  Vue Devtools have been disabled, see the comments in your background file for more info
⠋  Running completion hooks...error: 'setServers' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src/App.vue:232:10:

am getting error : WARN Devtools extensions are broken in Electron 6.0.0 and greater WARN Vue Devtools have been disabled

please help me ..

Answer (score 0):

Consider if you're going to use Electron 6 instead of Electron 5 for now, as it doesn't seems like they're gonna get the Devtools bug solved anytime soon.

From Electrons releases it seems to have been a bug since the release in august, and since it's not fixed yet, then you have to consider if you want Electron 6 or Vue Devtools

https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/releases

Comment: devtools issue is clear thank you , but this problem not solved error: 'setServers' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src/App.vue:234:10

Comment: Well it's telling you that `serServers` is defined, but never used.. Is it something you have defined? If so, then you should consider if you want to use it, otherwise just delete it